# unknown parameter: -conf Error in osm2pgrouting

Tags: ubuntu, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I was just going through the following tutorial **[HERE](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/osm2pgrouting.html#run-osm2pgrouting)**.

I have extracted all the files succesfully using the below commands:

```
cd ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop/
tar -xvzf data.tar.
```

But when i run the following  command:

```
osm2pgrouting -file "data/sampledata.osm" \
                          -conf "/usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml" \
                          -dbname pgrouting-workshop \
                          -user user \
  -host localhost \
                          -clean
```

I get an error as follows:

```
unknown parameter:  -conf
```

What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: A problem with proper escaping? Try to run the command by writing all parameters into a single line and omitting the ``\``. Still the same error?

Comment: @scai your awesome ! thanks !

Comment: Great :) I wrote my comment as an answer so that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with proper escaping? Try to run the command by writing all parameters into a single line and omitting the `\`. Still the same error?